# Ktor api won't change and refresh

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I'm using ktor for create rest api with kotlin but when i change api and run again response won't change.

This is my code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondText("Hi", ContentType.Text.Plain)
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

When run it for the first time work correct and show in localhost:8080

> Hi

But if i change

`call.respondText("Hi", ContentType.Text.Plain)`

to

`call.respondText("Hello", ContentType.Text.Plain)`

And run it again response no change and steel show **Hi** in localhost:8080

**Update**

If i close android studio and open it again and run its work and show **Hello**  but again if i change anything nothing will be change

i don't have any idea to why this is happening.

Comment: I do not have experience with Android Studio but the only time this happens for me in IntelliJ is when my run config is missing the build step. Verify if build is executed before running.

Answer (score 0):

It happens with me when android `instant run` feature is enabled.
Please consider to disable it and try again.